# What's causing segmentation fault with imbalanced learn oversampler?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, segmentation-fault

I'm using the `imbalanced-learn` package for the SMOTE algorithm and am running into a bizarre problem. For some reason, running the following code leads to a segfault (Python 3.9.2). I was wondering if anyone had a solution. I already posted this to the GitHub issues page of the package but thought someone here might have ideas before the bug gets sorted out.

```
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

over = SMOTE(k_neighbors=3)

X = np.array([[35., 18.],
       [80.,  0.],
       [18., 40.],
       [58.,  0.],
       [73., 20.],
       [20., 26.],
       [53., 29.],
       [ 0., 20.],
       [ 2., 40.],
       [18., 35.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [22., 40.],
       [ 0., 33.],
       [37., 60.]])

y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
over.fit_resample(X,y)
```

Leads to (macOS 13.3.1 (22E261)):

```
zsh: segmentation fault  python
```

Version info:

```
Python 3.9.2
# Name                    Version                   Build
imbalanced-learn          0.10.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
numpy                     1.23.5           py39he696674_0  
numpy-base                1.23.5           py39h9cd3388_0  
scipy                     1.10.0           py39h91c6ef4_1
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with Python 3.8.13 on OSX 13.2.1.